# MySQL Loop Query left from entry split entry

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I need a query in MySQL with result:

```
Article | Box Quantity    
6781234 |      128
6781234 |      128
6781234 |      128
6781234 |      116
 745694 |      128
 745694 |      128
 745694 |      128
 745694 |       16
 563217 |      256
 563217 |      256
 563217 |      256
 563217 |       32
```

My tabel is build with

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id` int(11),
    `order_no` int(11),
    `quantity` int(11),
    `box` int(11)
);
```

and I have filled 3 inserts

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `order_no`, `quantity`, `box`) VALUES (1, '6781234', '500', '128'), (2, '745694', '400', '128'), (3, '563217', '800', '256');
```

For example:

```
order_no| quantity | box    
6781234 |      500 | 128
 745694 |      400 | 128
 563217 |      800 | 256
```

I'm still not certain in MySQL but I solved it in PHP with an FOR-LOOP like

```
$ARTICLE = 6781234;
$QUANTITY = 500;
$BOX = 128;

for($LEFT=$QUANTITY;$LEFT>=$BOX;$LEFT=$LEFT-$BOX){
        echo $ARTICLE." | ".$BOX."<br/>";
}

echo $ARTICLE." | ".$LEFT
```

In MYSQL I have no inception idea to start. It would be great if anybody can give a tip for help. Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same php logic once you have the data extracted from mysql table

```
//establish mysql or mysqli connection
//I use mysqli and call its handle $mysqli
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM orders");
while($r = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    extract($r);
    for($LEFT=$quantity;$LEFT>=$box;$LEFT=$LEFT-$box){
            echo $order_no." | ".$box."<br/>";
    }
    echo $order_no." | ".$LEFT."<br>";
}
```

Comment: not sure of your goal, but you might find the following useful inside of the while loop: `echo "{$order_no} -- Full Boxes: ".floor($quantity / $box)." of {$box} with ".($quantity % $box)." pieces left over.<br>";`

Comment: hey thank you for your answers. I want to solve it in SQL query as SELECT() not in PHP